# random.sample() not working being recognised as a function

Tags: python

This is my code and im trying to select 5 items from the 'ticket' list and create a winning combination, but the function sample doesn't seem to be working.

It returns the following:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sample'
```

This is pretty weird as the program does use the random library to correctly generate the ticket.

```
from random import *


#This function will split the input name into characters and return it as a list
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

#This function will generate the remaining numbers missing from the maximum number of characters (in this case 13)
def ticket_generation(name, number_of_characters):

    #Ticket
    ticket = split(name)

    #Checking whether all the remaining numbers are generated
    while len(ticket) < number_of_characters:
        number = randint(0,50)
        ticket.append(number)

    winning_combination = random.sample(ticket, k=5)
    return(ticket)
    return(winning_combination)

print(ticket_generation("Leonardo", 13))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove random. since you've imported the entire package

```
winning_combination = sample(ticket, k=5)
```

Otherwise, don't import the entire package

```
from random import randint, sample
winning_combination = sample(ticket, k=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have imported all from random. No need to write random.sample(,,,) simple sample (,,,) should work.

> `winning_combination = sample(ticket, k=5)`